# "Star Trek: The Next Generation" episode focusing on crew members below command level

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

There's an episode of *The Next Generation* that focuses on the Ensign-level crew members, rather than the Command-level crew.

I cannot remember the name of this episode - and I do not remember enough details about the episode to look up the name of this episode either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's Season 7 Episode 15 of Star Trek: The Next Generation, entitled ["Lower Decks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Decks).

> In this episode, a rare insight into the lives of junior officers aboard the Enterprise is covered. The plot focuses on four crew members that are wondering about their crew evaluations.
>
> The episode follows the character Sito Jaxa (played by Shannon Fill) introduced in "The First Duty" (S5, E19) and provides more backstory for the Cardassian, Bajoran, and Federation conflict.

Comment: A quick and good answer.  Thank you. :)

Comment: You might also want to check out "The First Duty" as it focuses on Starfleet Cadets; http://www.jammersreviews.com/st-tng/s5/firstduty.php

Comment: @Richard With at least one of the characters from that episode showing up in "Lower Decks", thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This type of episode is known as a [Lower Deck episode](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LowerDeckEpisode) - this episode is (obviously) the trope namer.  TvTropes link, btw.

Comment: That was TNG? I thought it was Voyager. Or did Voyager also do such an episode?

Comment: @eidylon You're probably thinking of VOY 1x16, [Learning Curve](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Learning_Curve_(episode)), where Tuvok tried to train some Maquis who weren't fitting into the crew for various reasons

Comment: @Izkata, maybe. definite similarities. I feel like the episode I'm thinking of had a shot of one of the characters' faces from outside a small hull window, I think at the end of a corridor or Jeffries tube (tho that wouldn't make a lot of sense) on ... well, the lower decks. I can see the shot in my head, but don't remember which it might have been from.

Comment: @eidylon Ah yes, I think I remember that.  There was one crewmember who avoided the rest of the crew and hid himself in the furthest part of the ship, developing his "theory of everything" or whatever it was.  Janeway made it a point to bring him out of his shell, if I'm recalling correctly.  No idea what episode it was.

Comment: Oh, sounds familiar, yeah...

Comment: @eidylon [Good Shepherd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Good_Shepherd_(episode))

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that's the episode.

Answer (score 3):

This subject matter is also discussed in *Star Trek: Voyager*'s ["Good Shepherd"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Shepherd_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29) (Season 6, Episode 20).

> Captain Janeway goes on an away mission with three troubled crew-members in shuttle.

["Learning Curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_Curve_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) (Season 1, Episode 16) also looks at it to a lesser extent.

> Some of the crew of the Maquis ship *Val Jean* which had become part of the *Voyager* crew due to the destruction of their own vessel experience problems getting along with the Federation crew. They have to get trained by Tuvok to better operate aboard their new ship. Both crews are stranded on the other side of the Galaxy from Earth, after being abducted by an extra-galactic alien that abducted and medically tortured the crews of *Voyager* and *Val Jean*, killing a number of them in the process.

Comment: There's also the DS9 episode "Empok Nor", which puts some spotlight on the crewmen.